# Sending POST request with Amplifyjs

Tags: ajax, amplifyjs

I want to send this POST request by amplifyjs

```
amplify.request.define('createItem', 'ajax', {
    url: baseApiUrl + '/create/?folderid={folderid}',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

after that, the execution will be something like this:

```
createItem = function (callbacks, folderid, itemdata) {
    return amplify.request({
        resourceId: 'createItem',
        data : {
            folderid: folderid,
            data: itemdata
        },
        success: callbacks.success,
        error: callbacks.error
    });
};
```

`"itemData"` is already a JSON string. I keep getting the Bad Request status code.

If I change the API URL to:

```
baseApiUrl + '/create
```

And after that pass:

```
return amplify.request({
    resourceId: 'createItem',
    data :data,
    success: callbacks.success,
    error: callbacks.error
});
```

It works just fine, but I need to pass the Id as well. Maybe, I'm missing something here.

Comment: Where are you passing this to? Web API?

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine `folderid` and `itemdata` into a single `data` object. When Amplify reads your data object it will extract the `folderid` property and place it in the URL of the request. Then it will POST the remaining properties of the data object.